# Assigning a Group ID for the data from the same day in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to check if the observations are from the same day and assign the same group id if they are on the same day. My data looks like

```
EmployeeID         StartDateTime       EndDateTime             ShiftType         SameDay
                 
12041     2018-07-20 13:30:00.000   2018-07-20 14:00:00.000    Shift                1
12041     2018-07-20 14:00:00.000   2018-07-20 15:00:00.000    Shift                1
12041     2018-07-20 16:00:00.000   2018-07-20 17:00:00.000    Public               2
12041     2018-07-20 17:00:00.000   2018-07-20 17:06:00.000    Shift                1
12041     2018-07-20 19:00:00.000   2018-07-20 20:00:00.000    Public               2
37821     2018-07-20 09:00:00.000   2018-07-20 10:00:00.000    Shift                3
```

The "SameDay" column is the group ID I want to create. Basically, if for each employee(employeeID), if the entry is on the same day based on the start date time and the end date time, "as long as they have the same shift type".

I tried to do this using Row Number/Partition by but it's not working.

```
row_number() over (partition by EmployeeID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime,  ShiftType order by EmployeeID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) as SameDay
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the grouping separately and then join that data set back with your original rows. I used some [common table expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE's) to isolate the grouping.

**Sample data**

```
create table observation
(
  EmployeeId int,
  StartDateTime datetime,
  EndDateTime datetime,
  ShiftType nvarchar(10)
);

insert into observation (EmployeeID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, ShiftType) values
(12041, '2018-07-20 13:30:00.000', '2018-07-20 14:00:00.000', 'Shift' ),
(12041, '2018-07-20 14:00:00.000', '2018-07-20 15:00:00.000', 'Shift' ),
(12041, '2018-07-20 16:00:00.000', '2018-07-20 17:00:00.000', 'Public'),
(12041, '2018-07-20 17:00:00.000', '2018-07-20 17:06:00.000', 'Shift' ),
(12041, '2018-07-20 19:00:00.000', '2018-07-20 20:00:00.000', 'Public'),
(37821, '2018-07-20 09:00:00.000', '2018-07-20 10:00:00.000', 'Shift' );
```

**Solution**

The first CTE (`cte_group`) defines the grouping values. The second CTE (`cte_groupnum`) then assigns an ID to each group. Using `g.ShiftType desc` ordering with the `row_number()` function to get the exact same numbering as in the question.

```
with cte_group as
(
  select o.EmployeeId,
         convert(date, o.StartDateTime) as StartDate,
         convert(date, o.EndDateTime) as EndDate,
         o.ShiftType
  from observation o
  group by o.EmployeeID,
           convert(date, o.StartDateTime),
           convert(date, o.EndDateTime),
           o.ShiftType
),
cte_groupnum as
(
  select g.*,
         row_number() over(order by g.EmployeeId, g.StartDate, g.EndDate, g.ShiftType desc) as GroupId
  from cte_group g
)
select o.*,
       gn.GroupId
from observation o
join cte_groupnum gn
  on  gn.EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId
  and gn.ShiftType = o.ShiftType
  and gn.StartDate = convert(date, o.StartDateTime)
  and gn.EndDate = convert(date, o.EndDateTime);
```

**Result**

```
EmployeeId StartDateTime           EndDateTime             ShiftType GroupId
---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- --------- -------
12041      2018-07-20 13:30:00.000 2018-07-20 14:00:00.000 Shift     1
12041      2018-07-20 14:00:00.000 2018-07-20 15:00:00.000 Shift     1
12041      2018-07-20 16:00:00.000 2018-07-20 17:00:00.000 Public    2
12041      2018-07-20 17:00:00.000 2018-07-20 17:06:00.000 Shift     1
12041      2018-07-20 19:00:00.000 2018-07-20 20:00:00.000 Public    2
37821      2018-07-20 09:00:00.000 2018-07-20 10:00:00.000 Shift     3
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83e3148d77b2aa3bc0e2284bc75b7223) to see it in action and with intermediate CTE results.